# How to get options from Wordpress Jetpack

Tags: wordpress, jetpack

I create wordpress theme with infinite scroll (from Jetpack plugin) and I don't know how to get Jetpack option for this feature.
I must get this option to create alternative pagination if infinite scroll is disabled.

I try to use two solutions, but each returns false.

```
get_option( 'infinite_mode' );
Jetpack_Options::get_option( 'infinite_mode' );
```

Comment: Have you searched the options menu for Jetpack options to ensure you're using the correct key? `wp-admin/options.php` is the URL

Comment: Yeah I don't think `infinite_mode` is a Jetpack Option key? What exactly are you trying to grab from the options? If it's infinite scroll you can check that with `current_theme_supports( 'infinite-scroll' );` or get Infinite Scroll settings with `get_theme_supports( 'infinite-scroll' );`